# How to change the default colors.xml created in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, colors

Whenever I create a new project in Android Studio, this is the `colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

The number of colors in this is very less and I have to add more colors each and every time.

Is there a way I can add these colors at once, so that every time, it is created, we get all those colors in the file?

I searched about this on Google but didn't find any answer I could understand.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This colors are by default color. you can't change it. Once project is ready you can change it after.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. But is there a way we can modify these in the source files of Android Studio or something?

Comment: @E.Praneeth Nope